# Mongodb find near users point with distance

Tags: mongodb, gis, 2dsphere

we have a problem for find near users point with distance in mongodb database. the our main problem is we can't aggregate near point with distance. we used $geoWithin with below query:

> db.users.find({ location:    { $geoWithin:
>         { $centerSphere: [ [ 51.410608, 35.744042 ], 2/6378.1 ] } } }).sort({"user.lastActivity":-1}).limit(100)

this query return 100 records from 500204 records in 0.005 sec.

we also used $nearSphere with below query:

> db.users.find({ location: { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type: "Point",
>   coordinates: [ 51.410608, 35.744042 ] }, $maxDistance: 2000 } }
>   }).sort({"user.lastActivity":-1}).limit(100)

this query return 100 records from 500204 records in 8.486 sec.

we also used geoNear with below query:

> db.runCommand( { geoNear: "users",
>                      near: { type: "Point" ,  coordinates: [ 51.410608, 35.744042 ]},
>                      spherical: true ,
>                      "limit": 100, "maxDistance": 2000 } )

this query return 100 records from 500204 records in 6.215 sec. this query find near point with distance but execute takes a long time.

we add index 2dsphere on users.locations field.

1) please say me about why $nearSphere execute time more than $nearSphere?
2) how to find near point with $nearSphere and calculate return records distance?
3) how to execute geoNear with less time?

we also find near point with mysql on 1394018 records. execute time is 0.0011. this time is really fantastic.

> SELECT st_distance_sphere(fld_geom, point( 35.744042,51.410608)) as
>   distance from testgeom where st_distance_sphere(fld_geom, point(
>   35.744042,51.410608))<=2000 LIMIT 100

i think mysql spatial is very powerful than mongodb spatial.

Answer (score 0):

To increase performance create a 2D sphere index for the collection on the field being searched.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#create-a-2dsphere-index

There are other types of geospatial indices as well. This should substantially increase performance at the cost of memory utilization.

Comment: Thanks. We will add 2dsphere index but problem not solved. Performance not good.

Comment: Then consider keeping unrelated data in different collections, or taking a look at your server specs.

Comment: thanks for your solution. we could run this section on mysql but we can't do this. mysql really good performance for this operation.

Comment: get the execution plan for the query with `<your query>.explain()` and see what is going on

Answer (score 0):

$nearSphere gives you result sorted by distance, while $getWithin doesn't. 
I don't think sql query sorts the documents by distance (just filters them like $geoWithin)

- Doesn't make sense to use sort on user.lastActivity with $nearSphere - you just override your distance sort from $nearSphere.

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#sort-operation)